# Opening datasource on 1 form in another raises error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a delphi project with multiple forms in it. On one of these forms I have a dataset which contains fields, I would like to open this dataset on another form, however I get the following error message which I've not seen before :

**Project raised exception class $C0000005 with message access violation at 0x005f536f:read of address 0x000000e8.**

Am I doing something wrong or going about this the wrong way?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Code:

```
uses frm1

procedure Tfrm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  frm1.ds.DataSet.Open;
end;
```

Code for button click on frm1 to launch frm2

```
procedure Tfrm1.btnCreateClick(Sender: TObject);
var Form2 : tfrm2;    
begin
  Form2 := tfrm2.Create(self);
  Form2.Editing := False;
  try
    Form2.ShowModal
  finally
    Form2.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Any code shown would raise the potential for help significantly.

Comment: Probably the form should be created dynamically before open the dataset, but this is only a guess without seeing the actual code. Post the code or an example which expose the issue you are facing.

Comment: Question edited with code

Comment: Has the instance of frm1 been created before Tfrm2.FormCreate is called?  Put a debugger breakpoint on the line "frm1.ds[...]" and evaluate the value of frm1 when the breakpoint is hit.  If the value is Nil, that's the cause - frm1 hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Frm1 is already created, frm2 launches at the click of a button on frm 1

Comment: In that case, at the breakpoint I suggested, evaluate, in turn,  frm1, frm1.ds, and frm1.ds.dataset.  Are they all not Nil?  If any of them is Nil, that's your problem.

Comment: `tfrm2.Create(self)` should be `tfrm2.Create(nil)`.

Comment: Do the unit `frm1` and the form `frm1` share the same name? Your uses clause suggests that.

Comment: @Dag, if you have a problem and want help, why not produce a minimal compilable example that exposes your problem? We can do a lot of guessing here, but that is not how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Btw, when you show your code, please cut and paste it from your project, rather than trying to type it again when you write your q.  There is a mistake in the first bit you've quoted which  I'll leave you to spot.

Comment: @Dag Your 2nd code block doesn't confirm `frm1` is created. `frm1` is just a variable. `Tfrm1` is a class that can create an instance of `Tfrm2`. If you have code such as: `OtherForm1 := Tfrm1.Create(nil); OtherForm1.Show;` then it's very possilbe `frm1` is still **nil**. .... You need to use breakpoints and apply debugging as has been explained to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sample demonstrate very bad practice:

> Unit1 using Unit2
>
> Unit2 using Unit1

Create DataModule unit and use it from Unit1 and Unit2

Will be like this:

> Unit1 using Unit2 and DataModule unit
>
> Unit2 using DataModule unit

Anyway, your code should work. Reason why you get AccessViolation -- perhaps you have some events for TADOQuery/TADOTable and/or TDAtaSource which are not listed in your code sample

Answer (score 0):

Problably code is imcomplete but the problem is that you have not created an instance of form1. So frm1 is not available. So this code will avoid Access Violation.

```
uses frm1

procedure Tfrm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  frm1 := TForm1.Create(Application);
  frm1.ds.DataSet.Open;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would not recommend using data access components individually in each form, rather I would put them all in a Data Module. That way all forms of your application can have access to your data access components and also your application will look clean and organized.
About the error, it is important to mention that form1(with dataset) should call form2 through its Interface uses, and Form2(the one to call form1 dataset) should call form1 through its Implementation uses. I believe it will solve your problem. Let me know whether it worked.
J